# Keep forgetting to branch

Tags: git

I've been using git for a few days and keep forgetting to make a branch when I start working on something new, bug fix, etc.

So, I'll change a few files in master and then realize I should have created a branch and made my changes there.

Is there an easy way to create a new branch and pull over my changes (in master) without making a commit in master (aside from manually copying files around)?

Thanks!

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging - first snippet of code `$ git checkout -b branchname`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git checkout -b branchname
```

This will create a new branch called `branchname` at your current HEAD, without losing any data in your working directory.

If you have already accidentally commited something while on master—without having it pushed—you can also reset your master to the original state (for example to `origin/master` which is the last published or fetched state):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note that the latter command *will* throw away any changes you have made. So be careful with that :)

Comment: Thanks! I made a new branch, checked it out and my changes from master were there. I went back to my master branch and reverted a change. When I switched to my other branch the change had been reverted there too! I thought that things I do on one branch shouldn't effect changes on another branch. ??

Comment: Changes that haven’t been committed, and as such are only there in the working directory, will stay when checking out other branches *if* that change can be applied cleanly (i.e. no conflicts appear); otherwise it will abort the checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just `git checkout -b <branchname>` and your commits will be on the new branch.